# SCT-013-010 - Pulse on current threshold

Tags: circuit-design, current-measurement, comparator, atmega328p

I have an [SCT-013-010](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1089413/YHDC/SCT-013-010/1) current sensor. It has a measuring range of 0-20 A and outputs 0-1 V.

I need to create a circuit that uses this current sensor, and trimming a current threshold (using a trimmer) the circuit will generate a pulse on the output that will be used in order to detect if the load was switched on from my MCU (ATmega328P).

How I can do that?

**What I've done so far:**

Currently I'm using this CT in this configuration and I detect when the load is switched on by sampling the analog values and determining the on/off with a software based threshold, but my intent is to keep this logic out of my software and get a pulse to my ATmega328P when the load is switched on/off.

[image: circ]

Comment: Just add an analog comparator ... with a digital output. NB : there is a comparator in the MCU.

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/23551/how-to-use-the-analog-comparator-to-determine-when-an-analog-pin-has-reached-a-c

Comment: Thanks, but what is the threshold of the internal comparator? Also, the values that are coming out from the CT are floating +/- 1V...how the internal comparator will work?

Comment: The values coming out of the CT are **centered on 2.5V**, so no worries. If I remember well, the two inputs of the comparator are "accessibles", so one can wire the output of the CT on one input, and a chosen value (by a pot) on the other. See section 22 of the datasheet. <<<Overview  ...  The analog comparator compares the input values on the positive pin AIN0 and negative pin AIN1>>>

Answer (score 1):

A6 (Analog In 0 - positive) & A7 (Analog In 1 - negative) on Adruino Uno (et al) are the primary comparator inputs.  The 'proper' way to use them is to add a Vref to AIN0, use AIN1 for your varying voltage and set the triggering to 'AIN1 RISING' PAST the AIN0 setpoint.

But there is also an internal connection to AIN0; it may be switched to accept the bandgap internal reference voltage which is 1.1 V ±0.1 V.  As this varies from processor to processor a small calibration routine needs to be run either at programming time or during setup at each boot.

Similarly the AIN1 can be programatically sourced from the 6 (or 8) Analog input pins; however the ADC must be switched off while the comparator is using one of these selectable inputs.

The output value is switched by hardware into an internal register where it may be read by your program at any time.
Timer1 may also be linked via internal hardware to start/stop counting on a comparator trigger AND a Comparator interrupt may be instantly triggered by rising, falling or both edges from AIN1.

Setting Timer1 count to zero on one comparator interrupt then reading the counter value at another comparator interrupt, etc, etc can capture fast events, pulse widths and duty cycles easily.

Adapting your AIN1 to match the bandgap reference reduces external hardware dramatically.
A 10 turn, 5 kΩ pot set to between 40 & 60% will be fine -

```
[2.5V * 2k  / (2k  + 3k)]  = [ 2.5 * ( 2   / 5 ) = 2.5 * 0.40 = 1.0 V
[2.5V * 2k2 / (2k2 + 2k8)] = [ 2.5 * ( 2.2 / 5 ) = 2.5 * 0.44 = 1.1 V
[2.5V * 2k4 / (2k4 + 2k6)] = [ 2.5 * ( 2.4 / 5 ) = 2.5 * 0.48 = 1.2 V
```